# PyMySQL fails to authenticate specific user (MySQLdb succeeds)

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

Using the same database credentials, MySQLdb succeeds at authentication while pymysql does not. This happens only for one specific user.

```
>>> import pymysql
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.connect(**creds)
<_mysql.connection open to 'xxx' at edeae8>
>>> pymysql.connect(**creds)
...
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'xxx'@'10.x.x.x' (using password: YES)")
```

Does anyone have any clues as to what might be causing this? Is pymysql known to treat certain usernames specially? Or fail to handle certain characters in passwords appropriately?

Note that pymysql can connect just fine using other credentials:

```
>>> pymysql.connect(**other_creds)
<pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x7f6991558240>
>>> MySQLdb.connect(**other_creds)
<_mysql.connection open to 'xxx' at edeae8>
```

To be clear, the authentication that fails with PyMySQL succeeds with all other methods I've tried, including a command-line invocation of the `mysql` client using the same credentials.

Using Python 3.5.2

Comment: Does the user name or password contain any special characters (other than underscore)? I'm wondering if there's an escaping / URL-encoding issue.

Comment: Both are entirely ASCII. The username contains only lowercase alphanumerics. The failing password contains two punctuation characters, one of which is also contained in the password of the working credentials, and the other of which is an `@` . I'm setting up a test next to see if removing that `@` makes a difference.

Comment: For the record, I also tried running the password through `pymysql.escape_string`, which produced no changes -- as expected since there are no special MySQL characters in the string.

Comment: Further information: PyMySQL has no problem authenticating a new user with the same database permissions and password, and a username of the same form. It is still the only client that cannot authenticate the original user, however.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a database that needs an SSL connection? If so, you'll need to provide the root certificate explicitly. I ran into a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331500/does-pymysql-fully-support-mysql-authentication/59338672#59338672

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL encode the password if it contains any characters that conflict with the database URL format. The `@` you mentioned in comments would have this problem.

This can be done via `urllib.urlencode` or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm not sure I understand why the password parameter would need to be URL escaped -- I would expect that the password would not be passed in a URL. I would also expect the PyMySQL library to URL escape any field that did require escaping.

It may be that I'm just not understanding something, but in any case running the password through `urllib.parse.quote` first did nothing to alleviate the authentication failure.

Answer (score 1):

Almost two years later but i will leave the answer here anyway

This bug was reported in https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/804, marked as "not a bug" and closed. Pymysql is the only library that doesn't escape characters for you, so you need to convert your string to bytes before using it, like this:

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password=bytes('my-sécrét-pw', 'utf-8') ,
                             db='dbase')
```