# Does pymysql fully support MySQL authentication?

Tags: pymysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL (5.7.22) database hosted on AWS RDS using a function run through AWS Lambda, but am unable to connect to the database using `pymysql` due to an authentication error: `"Access denied for '<user>'@'<host>' (using password: YES)"`. Curiously, on an AWS instance that I've been using to debug the issue, I find that I am able to connect to the database using the same parameters with `mysqlclient`.

In case it's relevant, my password only contains alphanumeric characters.

Here is a minimal example I've used to connect to the database with the two packages using the `records` library (using bare libraries yields the same results):

```py
import pymysql
import MySQLdb

config = {}  # Dictionary with database credentials.



MySQLdb.connect(
            hostname=config['host'],
            port=config["port"],
            user=config['username'],
            passwd=config['password'],
            db=config['database'],
            connect_timeout=5,
        )
# Works fine

pymysql.connect(
            hostname=config['host'],
            port=config["port"],
            user=config['username'],
            passwd=config['password'],
            db=config['database'],
            connect_timeout=5,
        )

# raises pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '<user>'@'<host>' (using password: YES)")
```

Are there database configurations that are not supported by `pymysql` or require additional options?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that I needed to specify an SSL CA (the RDS root certificate that can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)):

```py
pymysql.connect(
            hostname=config['host'],
            port=config["port"],
            user=config['username'],
            passwd=config['password'],
            db=config['database'],
            connect_timeout=5,
            ssl={"ca": "./rds-ca-2015-root.pem"},
        )
```

I'm not entirely sure how the `MySQLdb` package avoids this step.